# IEnumerable<type> does not contain a definition of 'Contains'

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have 2 classes and 2 IEnumerable lists of those classes:

```
public class Values
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }
}

public class Holidays
{
    public DateTime holiday { get; set; }
}

IEnumerable<Values> values;
IEnumerable<Holidays> holidays;
```

Next, I am trying to select those 'values' where 'someDate' is not in 'holidays'

```
var query = values.Where(x=> !holidays.Contains(x.someDate));
```

However, this gives me the error of `IEnumerable<Holidays> does not contain a definition of 'Contains'`.

System.Linq is already added in the `using`s.

I believe this has to do something with the collections, but am not able to figure what.

Comment: As an aside, now would be a good time to start following .NET naming conventions, even for samples.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When you use [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.110).aspx), the object you're looking for must match the type `T` of the `IEnumerable<T>`. Thus, you cannot search `IEnumerable<A>` for a contained object of type `B` since there's no implicit way to compare the two.

As mentioned in other answers, use [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx) and pass in the comparison yourself.

Alternatively, this is also a case where you could use a [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) followed by [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.110).aspx), although this may be less readable in some cases:

```
var query = values
    .Where(x => !holidays
        .Select(h => h.holiday)
        .Contains(x.someDate));
```

Comment: In my case I was passing the whole object and not the string i needed. Woops

Comment: I had an `int` on one side and `int?` on the other so tricky to spot why it wasn't working. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 8):

[`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains) is a LINQ extension that takes (in your case) an instance of `Holidays` and checks if your enumeration contains that instance (or an instance that `Equals` the given argument).

You should use [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any) instead:

```
var query = values.Where(x=> !holidays.Any(h => h.holiday == x.someDate));
```

Comment: Be wary of the `Equals` function! It can have multiple meanings; there's default equality comparers that work one way, there's the ability to implement `IEquatable<T>` interfaces, and then there's the ability to pass in a new `EqualityComparer<T>` to `Contains`.

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to what everyone else has suggested already:

```
var holidayDates = new HashSet<DateTime>(holidays.Select(h => h.holiday));
var query = values.Where(x => !holidayDates.Contains(x.someDate));
```

In particular, if you have a lot of holidays, this change will make the per-value check much more efficient.

Comment: did you mean `holidayDates` on `holidayDays`?

Answer (score 4):

You probably want [Any()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
var query = values.Where(v => !holidays.Any(h => h.holiday == v.someDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare a `Holiday` object with a `DateTime`. Use [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method instead:

```
var query = values.Where(x=> !holidays.Any(e=>e.holiday ==x.someDate));
```

Or you can also use [`All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method:

```
var query = values.Where(x=> holidays.All(e=>e.holiday !=x.someDate));
```